# % in url http request java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do an http request in java but I get this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence: %Ne in query at index 80:

```
try {
     HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     String URL = "Example.com";
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
     String SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
     Log.e("iets",SetServerString);

} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems I cant use the character '%' in the query. But the thing is that I really need to use the '%' since it represents a space in my echonest.php.

How can I solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: A space is writer as %20 in a query.

Comment: Have you tried encoding the url? URLEncoder.encode(URL, "utf-8");

Comment: You may want to use URI templates; I happen to [have a library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) for that, but others also exist. In particular, if you use Guava, it has `Escaper`s for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use URLEncoder like this:

```
String URL = "www.example.com"?title=stormwatch&artist=Helvetic"+URLEncoder.encode("%","UTF-8")+"Nerds";
```

Modify your code:

```
try {
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String URL = "www.example.com/?title=stormwatch&artist=Helvetic"+URLEncoder.encode("%","UTF-8")+"Nerds";
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                Log.e("iets",SetServerString);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: `+"Nerds"` - you've forgotten to put that under double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

% is used to encode special characters in URLs. To encode the actual "%" character you need to use %25
The url will become:
http://bertenbevers.be/ProjectICT4/echonest.php?title=stormwatch&artist=Helvetic%25Nerds

There are ready made libraries to encode urls. It will help avoid other strange symbols like spaces, slashes etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your URL using [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

```
String URL = "http://bertenbevers.be/ProjectICT4/echonest.php?title=stormwatch&artist=" + URLEncoder.encode("Helvetic%Nerds", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Didn't downvote but you're encoding too much, such as the `=` and `&`. Many other answers have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a special character in your `URL` you should user `URLEncoder.encode(<your URL>)` method

for example :-
`String url = "http://bertenbevers.be/ProjectICT4/echonest.php?"+URLEncoder.encode("title=stormwatch&artist=Helvetic%Nerds");`

Hope this might help you in solving your problem